# getting all records from a table that match a result set

Tags: mysql, self-join

this is going to sound a bit bizarre ...but let me try to explain

```
id       phone
1        123
2        234
3        456
4        4564
5        9876
..............
1000       123
2000       234  
3000       456
5000       123
```

i need to a write a query in such a manner  that when i pull the first 5 records of the table the query will also search in the same table for the phone numbers that are occurring in the first 5 records

so the final result set will be

```
id      phone
1       123
2       234
3       456
4       4564
5       9876
1000    123
2000    234
3000    456
5000    123
```

i know i can separate the same query first pull the first 5 and then iterate through each of the phone numbers to pull records if they match the phone number.  but was looking to do a single statement ...if its possible ...

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
SELECT ...
FROM yourtable
WHERE phone IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT phone
    FROM yourtable
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT 5
)
```

?

Comment: it says limit cannot be supported in sub query

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select t1.id,t2.phone from yourtable as t1 
left join yourtable as t2 on t2.phone = t1.phone
```

Comment: why doesnt this work ....  Select t1.ad_id,t2.phone from rawdata as t1 
left join rawdata as t2 on t2.phone = t1.phone ORDER BY t2.phone ASC limit 20   ... i just added an order by and it seems to get stuck